# retrieving TOS value on a TCP socket

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I have a scenario where a client opens a TCP connection to a server after setting some IP TOS value (`setsockopt(.., IP_TOS, ..)`. On the server I want to retrieve the received TOS value and set that on the socket so that the received TOS is reflected back on server-client packets.

The problem is, on the server side, how can I retrieve the TOS value received from the client? I can assume that the client will not change the TOS value during the entire session, so it is sufficient to get and set the TOS value once initially.

Setting `IP_RECVTOS` and using ancillary data works for UDP but not for TCP sockets. How can something similar be achieved on TCP sockets? `getsockopt(2)` with `SO_PRIORITY` or `IP_TOS` returns the configured values on the local socket. So if I did a `setsockopt()` locally then the `getsockopt()` reflects that value. It is not reflecting what is received on the network.

Comment: just wondering, but why would you let a far-end configured option change _your_ outbound traffic priorities?

Comment: ToS has been superseded by DSCP for a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

The TOS value could change for every TCP datagram received.

So it's not a constant option to the **receiving** TCP socket.

From the latter one could conclude that it's not possible for the receiver to pull a value for TOS from the receiving TCP socket in terms of an option which's value might be read using `getsockopt()`.

As there is no such feature like "ancillary messages" available for TCP the only way I see to find out what the **sender** set as TOS is to directly inspect the received TCP datagram's headers.

Comment: Yes agree about the contradiction of TCP and a packet by packet quantity like TOS. That is why I had mentioned that we can assume that the client wont change the tos during the lifetime of the session for what it might be worth.  As for your comment of directly inspecting the received header, did you mean using something like iptables to read and set the DSCP values or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I hadn't had anything special in mind. I just wanted to point out that TOS values are not necessarily an attribute of a receiving socket. Moreover I'd say this might not even be the case if you do not change the TOS value of the sending socket, as during transmission of the TCP datagrams their headers might be modifed in this regard by the intermediate hops.

Comment: @SanjayT: You might have a look at libpcap to let the application monitor it's own incoming TCP connections at a lower level.

Comment: @SanjayT: Using `ipfw` might do also, anyhow as you only want to read the latter might bring to much overhead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will probably go with making changes in the kernel.